# From enumerator to map

Tags: clojure

I have an mail object that returns its headers as an Enumerator of Header objects, which have two methods, getName and getValue. I need to convert that to a nice Clojure map so I wrote this short function:

```
(defn extract-headers [message]
  (reduce (fn [hs h] (conj hs {(.getName h) (.getValue h)}))
          {}
          (enumeration-seq (.getAllHeaders message))))
```

Anything to change or improve here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `into`, for example:

```
(defn extract-headers [message]
  (let [headers (enumeration-seq (.getAllHeaders message))]
       (into {} (map #(vector (.getName %1) (.getValue %1)) headers))))
```

first, with `map` you build sequence of 2-element vectors, that later is converted into map

Answer (score 1):

Reading the other answer, a simple small improvement would be:

```
(defn extract-headers [message]
  (reduce #(conj %1 {(.getName %2) (.getValue %2)})
          {}
          (enumeration-seq (.getAllHeaders message))))
```

Only to make it a little shorter.

Comment: use of explicit `fn` could make life easier + it allows to put type hint before argument

Answer (score 1):

I rather like the into approach, I think it's more idiomatic to use a dedicated function than reduce, which is quite general.  However, I think using threading is easier to read long term.

```
(defn extract-headers [^Mail message]
  (letfn [(project [^Header h] (list (.getName h) (.getValue h)))]
    (->>
      message
      .getAllHeaders
      enumeration-seq
      (map project)
      (into {}))))
```

As you can see, I've also incorporated Alex's suggestion to use an explict fn, which avoids reflection.